# Displays the date in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How to change the display of dates in MySQL Workbench

Recorded as 16-01-2014 now

But  is necessary to do so: 16-01-2014

Comment: …are your two date formats exactly the same?

Comment: I'm developing an application to C # WinForm and when the text box insert such date 16-01-2014 then display for me completely different.
Only when I enter 16-01-2014 then it turns 01-16-2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your `SELECT` statements to get your dates rendered differently.

Change

```
 SELECT datestamp
```

to

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

MySQL Workbench is a client program that accesses MySQL database servers. You use the workbench to write queries to send to a MySQL server to get back data.

If you want your dates presented in a particular way, that's part of the queries you write.   If you use the queries built in to the workbench, *you can't change the date format it displays.*

Don't give in to the temptation to change the data type of your date and time columns in your table to VARCHAR(), and then fill them with values in the format you prefer. If you do that, you'll lose the ability to search your table on date ranges.

Comment: And how to do it in the MySQL Workbench because I'm just starting to learn it?
Excuse me.